# Google chrome cannot open any pages by google

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I had this problem where Google chrome stopped loading google.com. I followed what the details said but nothing. I closed the browser then opened again then it said that my chrome apps crashed and so did chrome. Did some research and I found that I had to delete cache, chrome apps, and it should be fixed. No luck. I could not download Google again in chrome, me edge, or firefox to update/fix the version I had only because all Google pages could not load. I did manage to get the latest version of the setup of google from downloading it from my school. I installed it but still no luck. Chrome does not crash when i open it anymore but does not want to load any google.com sites. The error I get it ERR_CONECTION_REFUSED. Other sites like this one and any social media will open in the browser fine. It's just Google that's the picky one.

Comment: please check if you are using any proxies and also test the same thing in incognito mode

Comment: It did not work in incognito and I don't use proxy. I can't open google.com mainly along with Google drive. YouTube yes can be opened but everything is not styled with css, java, etc. All of Google websites don't work or just load improperly with out the css, java to make it work